# Extra empty (white) space under the div when set width: 100vh

Tags: html, css

I have a horizontal scrollable div with different element inside.
I have set the  `width: 100vh`  because i have rotated the div for my horizontal scroll.
The problem is the `width: 100vh`  cause an extra white space under the div.
Have you got any solution for remove this space?

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 100vw;
  width: 100vh;
  transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(-100vh);
  transform-origin: top left;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  background: red;
}

.container {
  transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(-100vh);
  transform-origin: top left;
  height: calc(100vh - 112px);
  width: max-content;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.children1 {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  background: green;
}

.children2 {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="children1"></div>
    <div class="children2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why are you rotating your elements?

Answer (score 0):

You can fix your body's margins and it should be good.

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi yerme, thank you, I tried, but it doesn't work for my code.

Answer (score 0):

```
.wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  transform-origin: top left;
  background: red;
}

.container {
  transform-origin: top left;
  height: calc(100vh - 112px);
  width: max-content;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.children1 {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  background: green;
}

.children2 {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  background: yellow;
}
```

Comment: Hi JV10. I have found this solution for my horizontal scrollable div. Have you got any alternatives?

Comment: I think that way can help you! I edited my answer